# Angular Material - Overlapping div in internet explorer and safari browser

Tags: css, internet-explorer, angular-material

I started developing an app using angular material and the layout is well using chrome and firefox. However, when I'm using ie11 or safari (ipad), angular material's md-card are overlapping. This happens when the layout becomes **column** for devices with small screen.

**Internet explorer**

[image]
**Chrome**

[image]

Here's a codepen

```
http://codepen.io/rodwin/pen/rxWdMj?editors=100
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    /*background-color: #FFF;*/
    position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

.white {
    background-color: #fff;
}

#main {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 0;
}

#main .wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 10%;
 
 
}

.promo i {
    color: #ee6e73;
    font-size: 7rem;
    display: block;
}

.block-button {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.demo-container {
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.02s padding cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1);
    transition: 0.02s padding cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1);
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}



.tabsdemoDynamicHeight md-content h2:first-child {
margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}

md-content {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-cloak>
    <!--[if lt IE 10]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <header>
        
    </header>
    <main>
        <md-content id="main" ui-view="" flex="" class="anim-in-out ng-scope flex" data-anim-sync="true" data-anim-speed="300">
      
        <md-toolbar class="md-toolbar-tools" layout-align="center center" style="position: relative">
        
        <h2>
            <span>sample app</span>
        </h2>
        </md-toolbar>
        <md-content class="wrapper anim-fade" layout-padding layout="row" layout-xs="column" layout-sm="column">
        <div flex="33" flex-sm="100" flex-xs="100">
            <md-card class="md-hue-1">
                <md-card-title>
                    <md-card-title-text>
                        <span class="md-headline">Card with image</span>
                        <span class="md-subhead">Small</span>
                    </md-card-title-text>
                    <md-card-title-media>
                        <div class="md-media-md card-media">

                            <div class="center promo promo-example">
                                <a ui-sref="checkin.default" style="text-decoration: none;"><i class="large material-icons">input</i></a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </md-card-title-media>
                </md-card-title>
                <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
                    <md-button>Action 1</md-button>
                    <md-button>Action 2</md-button>
                </md-card-actions>
            </md-card>
        </div>
        <div flex="33" flex-sm="100" flex-xs="100">
            <md-card class="md-hue-1">
                <md-card-title>
                    <md-card-title-text>
                        <span class="md-headline">Card with image</span>
                        <span class="md-subhead">Small</span>
                    </md-card-title-text>
                    <md-card-title-media>
                        <div class="md-media-md card-media">
                            <div class="center promo promo-example">
                                <a ui-sref="devicesetup" style="text-decoration: none;"><i class="large material-icons">phonelink_setup</i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </md-card-title-media>
                </md-card-title>
                <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
                    <md-button>Action 1</md-button>
                    <md-button>Action 2</md-button>
                </md-card-actions>
            </md-card>
        </div>
        <div flex="33" flex-sm="100" flex-xs="100">
            <md-card class="md-hue-1">
                <md-card-title>
                    <md-card-title-text>
                        <span class="md-headline">Card with image</span>
                        <span class="md-subhead">Small</span>
                    </md-card-title-text>
                    <md-card-title-media>
                        <div class="md-media-md card-media">
                            <div class="center promo promo-example">
                                <a ui-sref="settings" style="text-decoration: none;"><i class="large material-icons">settings_applications</i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </md-card-title-media>
                </md-card-title>
                <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
                    <md-button>Action 1</md-button>
                    <md-button>Action 2</md-button>
                </md-card-actions>
            </md-card>
        </div>
    </md-content>
        </md-content>
    </main>

  
  <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  
  <!-- Your application bootstrap  -->
  <script type="text/javascript">    
    /**
     * You must include the dependency on 'ngMaterial' 
     */
    angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial']);
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Appreciate any assistance or suggestion on fixing this kind of layout issue.
(Please bear with my lack of css skills)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the md-content parent of the cards to:

```
<md-content class="wrapper anim-fade" layout-padding layout="row" layout-wrap></md-content>
```

I also was seeing some issues with the md-card-title in IE 11 that can be fixed by adding flex="initial":

```
<md-card-title flex="initial">
```

Only issue now is that in between certain breakpoints the third card might jump to the next row (only in IE). You could fix that by making the last card flex="30", but that might not be ideal for your situation.

Information on flex="initial" found here: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6217

Information on IE 11 layout issues found here: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5382

Updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpZEqB

Answer (score 0):

I had the same overlapping issue. Try to give a 'min-height: 1px;' style for your md-card. Hope this works.